# simple HTML5 drop file site website which zip the dropped files

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I would like to create a HTML5 website which the user simply drop the files and press a "submit" button which a javascript function creates a .zip archive of the dropped files.

My question is: Is this possible without upload the dropped files in the website BUT only by using the path of the saved files (i.e "c:\test\droppedfile1.exe", "c:\test\droppedfile2.exe") 
and create the .zip file in a local folder?

Comment: No, you can't create the zip file in a local folder. The browser will not reveal actual pathnames to JavaScript code. You can use HTML5 file APIs to read the files, however, and construct the zip file on the fly, assuming you've got the appropriate JavaScript code to do so.

Answer (score 3):

while you cant read files directly from the fs, the drop event do allow you to read the file source and (in therory) pipe the content to [Jszip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/) and then allow the user to "download" the zip file

[Here](http://html5demos.com/file-api) is and html5 drag and drop demo showing reading an image file with out getting access to the client path or uploading the file to the server

Comment: This is a pretty interesting plug-in you've referenced.  No idea why someone downvoted this.

Comment: For whoever downvoted this, can you mention why you did this?  Maybe I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not in plain HTML/JS. HTML/JS have no access to your hard drive. In fact, when you use a file upload box, the `value` is set to `C:/fakepath/nameoffile.ext` (where `nameoffile.ext` is the file name on the disk).

If you drag-drop or copy-paste files, they become blobs. In this case, the original file path is completely mangled -- it becomes something like `blob://lots-and-lots-of-gibberish`.

So no, HTML/JS do not provide you any way to get the file paths from an upload or upload from a provided file path.

---

However, on Chrome, there is the HTML5 [filesystem API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html), which will probably help. [Here's a tutorial on it](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Note that this will require extra permissions and won't work on other browsers just yet.

---

Using the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), you can read the data in selected files. You *cannot* get their paths, but you *can* read the data in a file selected in an upload box (or a drag dropped file), and use your JS function to zip the files.

Comment: The file path is available if the browser supports the Filesystem API.

Comment: @RayNicholus — When did they lift the per-web-app sandboxing restriction on that API?

Comment: @RayNicholus: Included that, but it's not really ready for websites to use (because of the chrome-only thing)

Comment: Thers the normal file API. he did state it going to happen after a dran and drop. so getting the file contents arnt that but a problem. and achiving the final goal is possible whithout having the file path

Comment: @Manishearth Yes, access to the full path of a file is restricted to Chrome 21+ since no other version of any other browser supports the Filesystem API at this time.  I agree, this is a bit limiting.  Just wanted to point out this possibility though.

Comment: @VeXii: You're not making any sense here.

Comment: @Manishearth theres a html5 file api that allows users to drag and drop files to the browser after witch you can use the html5 FileReader to read the contents of the file. while this DONT tell you the path of the file (its in the browser sandbox) you can stil work/manipulate the file and then allow the user to download it

Comment: @VeXii: Yes, I mentioned it in the last section, read again. It's largely unsupported and annoying.

Comment: @Manishearth VeXii seems to be talking about the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), which has wide browser support (every browser other than IE9 and earlier).  My initial comment referred to the [Filesystem API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/), which is only supported in Chrome 21+.

Comment: @Manishearth File API is supported by all the [major browsers (Even IE10)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi)

Comment: @VeXii: Ah, but the File API doesn't allow you to get paths. ANyway, I added a bit about it.

Comment: @VeXii: ....which was not asked for in the question :/ The question asked for file paths _specifically_

Comment: no he wants to work whith files client side and he Thinks that he needs the Real path. but then you need to look at the qustion and see what is the goal and do he want somthing on the way thats Needet. in this case the browser sandbox is more then sufficient. and informing him of that is the propper way to go about it (not pointing towards none standart api's)

Comment: @Manishearth yes and i just responted.